# How to remove spaces between spans?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've no idea why my span showing extra spaces

[image]

I've tried applying `padding: 0 px !important;`

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/536juzfn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spaces comes from the linebreak, if you remove the linebreak the spaces are gone.

```
<span>T</span><span>h</span><span>a</span><span>n</span><span>k</span><span>s</span><span>;</span>
```

Comment: Oh wow... how do we begin to know that ??? haha Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces appear since you have new lines and tabs between the `<span>` tags.

#### Solution 1

If you remove all of the space between the tags, there are no extra spaces:

```html
<h1>
    <span>T</span><span>h</span><span>a</span><span>n</span><span>k</span><span>s</span><span>;</span>
</h1>
```

#### Solution 2

Alternatively, you can apply the css property `white-space-collapse: discard;` or `display: flex;` on the parent.

`white-space-collapse` is not fully implemented, so you should be using a **flexbox** for now.

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fcup764x/1/

Comment: I also like the CSS trick !! Thanks ✨

Answer (score 0):

The `whitespace` appears because of `line-break` on your html code.
To remove it, simply, set `flex` layout on parent `h1` tag as follows.

```
h1 {
  ...
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Good stuff, good to know! 